# How to make GetAddress.io petelawrence API work with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, guzzle

I'm using GetAddress.io api and would like to use PHP version of code from here

[Address.io API By PeteLawrence](https://github.com/PeteLawrence/getaddress#usage)

I'm using codeigniter. Can someone guide my where to put which folder/files to make this work.

I have tried and now it's giving me all sorts of errors :/

or if you can assists me to make GetAddress.io api work using codeigniter that would be a big help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a library -or helper- for Codeigniter.

Basically, you can upload all files under `application/libraries` (or `system/libraries`). Also please try to do something(write some code) before posting questions here.

You can check [Codeigniter Libraries Document](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html)